# Alternating random variable

Tags: probability

here is the problem setting:

We have the probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{B},\mathbb{P})$ with $\Omega=[0,1]$ and $\mathbb{P}=\lambda|_{\Omega}$  (Lebesgue-measure) and the random variable
$$X_k(\omega) =
\begin{cases}
(-1)^k\cdot k,  & \text{if $\omega\in \left[\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2k},\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2k}\right]$ } \\
0, & \text{else.}
\end{cases}$$

- What is $\mathbb{E}[X_k]$ and converge it?
- Converge $X_K$ in probability ?

My answers:

- $\mathbb{E}[X_K]=(-1)^k\cdot k\cdot \int\limits_\Omega 1(\omega)_{\{I\}}\,d\mathbb{P}=(-1)^k$
- Definition of converge in probability means that $\mathbb{P}(|X_k-X|>\epsilon)\to 0$ for $k\to \infty$. For the special case of the random variable $X_k$ we get the expression
  $$\mathbb{P}(|X_k-X|>\epsilon)=1- \mathbb{P}(|X_k-X|\leq\epsilon)=1-\mathbb{P}(X_n-\epsilon\leq X\leq X_n+\epsilon)=1-2\epsilon.$$
  Is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

By inspection, $X_n(\omega) \to_n 0$ because Lebesgue measure on the $A$: $X_n \neq 0$ converges to $0$. At the same time, $\mathbf{E}X_k = (-1)^k \neq 0$